# Jeffrey Lee 5.17 Equivalent conditions on commuting left-invariant vector fields on $GL(V)$

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Here is the question:

> Let $A,B \in \frak gl$$(V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and show that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (a) $[A,B] = 0$.
>
> (b) $\exp(sA)$ and $\exp(tB)$ commute for all $s,t \in \mathbb{F}$.
>
> (c) $\exp(sA +tB) = \exp(sA)\exp(tB)$ for all $s,t \in \mathbb{F}$.

(a) $\Rightarrow$ (b) follows by commutativity of the flows, but the rest is unclear. Expanding the power series out doesn't seem to help. For small enough $s$ and $t$ we can apply $\log$, but I'm not sure if this helps either.

I'm really clueless right now. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Hints: To get (c) from (a), recall that $\exp\left(u+v\right) = \exp u \cdot \exp v$ when $u$ and $v$ commute (given appropriate absolute-convergence conditions). To get (a) from (c), take the $s$-derivative at $0$ and then take the $t$-derivative at $0$. Similarly for deriving (a) from (b).

Comment: Okay, I think I can take it from here. Thanks!